# Enterprise OTA app update

Tags: ios, ota

I've got problem with OTA app update. When I'm downloading an update without  deleting currently installed application, iOS installing the same version of the app. If I want to get the new version I need to delete installed app and re-download it form my website.
Manifest, bundle-version and ipa files are updated as they should be.
My question is why SpringBoard is replacing my app with the same version?

Comment: Did you check the CFBundleVersion in your application plist? What's the number of the older version and the new version?

Answer (score 0):

because they're using the same bundleID ... i got the same problem when installing new version of my OTA app